# Figure out how to copy to constant memory (CUDA)

Tags: cudalink

I found a function. The help gives:

> `` CUDALink`Internal`CUDAConstantMemoryCopy[mem1, mem2] `` copies constant memory to and from host memory.

As of now I have not figured out how to use it. `mem1` should be host memory and `mem2` should be shared or constant memory. It can also be the other way around for the other direction. The function is defined in `CUDALink.m`. There is a function `constantMemoryQ` (Line 878 in CUDALink.m) that checks `"Sharing" -> constant` in CUDAMemory. I tested some ideas using `CUDAMemoryLoad` with some setting of `"Shared" -> Constant`, `Constant`, `"Sharing" -> Constant` but nothing was working to set shared to constant. 
It can be checked with `CUDAMemoryInformation[constMem]`. There is a note about sharing.

Can someone from experience tell or figure out from the code what to put in for `mem1` and `mem2`?

Comment: I have created a chat room on the subject. Its name is "CUDA constant memory". [Here is the link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28726555#28726555)